# What does "(SECURED)" mean in the title of Adobe Reader?

Tags: adobe-reader

I opened a PDF that I haven't looked at in a while and noticed that in Adobe Reader, the title becomes "filename.txt (SECURED) - Adobe Reader"

Can someone tell me what the "(SECURED)" denotes?

(Prior to today, FoxIT Reader had been my default PDF program, but due to work-related issues, I had to switch back to Adobe.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that the file is encrypted.

To quote Steven Madwin, an Adobe Employee:

> the application puts it in the title
>   bar as a visual clue that the user is
>   in an encrypted file. The default is
>   for the application (either Acrobat or
>   Reader) to display the file name,
>   encryption status, and the application
>   name in the title bar. You can replace
>   the file name with the document title,
>   but you cannot suppress the encryption
>   status. This was added to Acrobat 8
>   because too many users were viewing
>   encrypted PDF files and didn't
>   understand why they couldn't make
>   changes.

Comment: link: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/487179

Answer (score 4):

It means the file is protected in some way, there are restrictions on what you can do with it.

"If you receive a PDF that is protected by security features, you may need a password to open the document. Some protected documents have restrictions that prevent you from printing, editing, or copying content in the document. If a document has restricted features, any tools and menu items related to those features are dimmed."

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Reader/8.0/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7d75.html